# How do I elegantly zero-initialize an array of std::atomic?

Tags: c++, c++11, atomic, stdatomic

Let's say I have a class with a member array of `std::atomic`s, where the
array is sized via a computation (i.e. it may change based on other constants elsewhere in the program):

```
class Foo {
  static constexpr size_t kArraySize = ComputeArraySize();
  std::atomic<size_t> atomics_[kArraySize];
};
```

What is the most elegant way to ensure that the atomics are all initialized to
zero? Can I do better than looping over the array in `Foo`'s constructor and
explicitly storing zero? Does the answer differ for `std::array`?

Normally I would use a brace initializer here, but the derived length (which
may be long) makes it difficult.

Note that I cannot assume that the instance of `Foo` has static storage
duration.

Comment: declare as `std::atomic<size_t> atomics_[kArraySize] = {};` ? I'm not sure what the rules are for atomic initialization

Comment: ... Is to do nothing. Everything static is zero-initialized at program startup.

Comment: @Ryan Haining: Yep, that does work for a plain C style array. Doesn't seem to work for `std::array<std::atomic<size_t>, N>` though, even though the standard seems to say it should.

@n.m.: "Note that I cannot assume that the instance of Foo has static storage duration".

Comment: "Doesn't seem to work for std::array<std::atomic<size_t>, N>". Works for me. Which compiler version are you using?

Comment: I can vouch for that. It does work as expected with gcc 4.8.2 and clang 3.4.1.

Comment: Thanks, all. I can't seem to reproduce the issue with a small program, only one with multiple levels of template instantiation. This is a Google-internal version of GCC and Clang, so it's possible it's weird somehow; will file an internal bug. If one of you submits an answer, I'll be happy to mark it accepted.

Comment: @jacobsa as you said, it supports aggregate initialization but I wasn't clear on what it does with the omitted elements

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Okay, I believe I've worked this through. Both of these will initialize all of
the atomics to zero:

```
std::atomic<size_t> plain_array[kArraySize] = {};
std::array<std::atomic<size_t>, kArraySize> std_array = {};
```

Here's the logic:

- [dcl.init.aggr]/1 defines arrays to be aggregates.
- [array.cons]/1 mandates that `std::array` also be an aggregate.
- [dcl.init.aggr]/7 says that if there are fewer elements of the initializer
  list than there are members in the aggregate, then the remaining members
  shall be initialized from an empty initializer list. In this case, that's
  all members.
- [dcl.init.list]/3 defines list-initialization from an empty list for a class
  with a default constructor (as with `std::atomic`) to cause
  value-initialization.
- [dcl.init]/7 says that classes without user-provided constructors are
  zero-initialized. Assuming that `std::array<T>` contains an array of `T`,
  and that the zero representation of `std::atomic<size_t>` is what we expect,
  then we're good.

Now, `std::atomic` *does* have a user-provided constructor, just not a
user-provided *default* constructor (the latter is explicitly defaulted). So
it doesn't technically fit the conditions of the last point. But it seems this
is an [error](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1368) in the standard, and has been [fixed](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/commit/7eed4036396d73f7c75719808119d993e840ce8c) in more recent
drafts.

Comment: I believe the underlying atomic objects are left in an uninitialized state due to the surprising behavior described in http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0883r0.pdf. Default initialization does not do what you would expect here.

Comment: @Joe Seems to have been fixed http://www.wg21.link/p0883